# How to show that the limit of a fibonacci sequence equates to 1 as n goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, fibonacci-numbers

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f_{n+1} f_{n-1}}{f_n^2} = 1$$

I tried expanding both the numerator and denominator to probably cancel out but that did not work... I also split it up into different fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Take [Cassini's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities):
$$
f_{n-1}f_{n+1} - f_n^2 = (-1)^n
$$
divide by $f_n^2$, and use that $f_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: This identity is the source of the [Fibonacci area paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle). See also http://yozh.org/2011/05/15/an-area-paradox/.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** when $n\to\infty$, $$f_n \sim \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\phi^n$$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.